# Bulb glows full brightness at which time of $I$-$t$ graph?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, power

[image]

I know that for first question,resistance increases..
In second question,it is asked to find the power when bulb glows at full brightness,
I think it is **NOT** 1A*200V=200w

What i think is that,we should take current at t1,and not at t0,because,
the bulb only starts to glow after t1(when heat is produced enough), and that decrease  in current from t0 to t1 is because the bulb's filament is getting more and more   hotter.
So probably it would be 0.5A*200V=100w

But i dont know if what i think is correct,or any complex physics would interfere here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your convictions are correct, from the graph you see that the current in the bulb reaches a steady state at 0.5 A, this steady state current certainly corresponds to the normal operating brightness of the bulb and thus corresponds to the maximum brightness level. So that power is given by $P=IV=(0.5A)(200V)$.

Just from looking at the shape of the graph, it appears that the filament reaches its operating temperature in such a way as to cause an exponential increase in resistance that leads to a corresponding exponential decrease in the filament current.